# SQL weighted revenue query

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

6I have 3 tables. Examples below.

```
Weight
Channel WeightFirst WeightMiddle    WeightLast
Dir      40         45              50
NatS     0          0               0
PC       20         25              30
UnRef    40         45              50

Sales
saleID  revenue
32150   1600.00
32153   516.00

Visits
visitID saleID  visitDate       channel visitRevenue
4479433 32153   2014-12-09 15:00:41.000 NatS    NULL
4479434 32153   2014-12-09 14:55:21.000 PC  NULL
4479435 32153   2014-12-09 15:09:01.000 UnRef   NULL
4755575 32150   2014-12-07 16:41:24.000 NatS    NULL
4756323 32150   2014-12-07 16:52:56.000 PC  NULL
4756324 32150   2014-12-06 20:49:41.000 Dir NULL
```

I need to calculate visitRevenus in the Visits table based on the WeightFirst, WeightMiddle, WeightLast in the Weight table.

First visitDate in the Visits table gets WeightFirst, last visitDate gets WeightLast, and everything in between those dates gets WeightMiddle.

For example saleID 32153 has the first visitDate as visitID 4479434, so PC gets a WeightFirst of 20, then visitID 4479433 gets 0 for NatS, and visitID 4479435 gets 50 for UnRef. Total weight is 70. With saleID revenue in Sales being 516.00 
I need to divide 516.00 by 70, then multiply the result by each weight and update visitRevenue in the Visits table with that result.

So PC would get 147.4285714285714 and UnRef would get 368.5714285714286. Add them together and it's 516.

The table I have hold more than just 2 saleIDs, many channels, and large amounts of visitDates. I need some SQL to update visitRevenue 
with these calculated figures but am having trouble getting started. Any help would be most welcome! And if anymore info is required please ask.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry formatting of example tables messed up

Comment: What if two visits have a tie for first?   Do they both get the WeightFirst weight?

Comment: for saleID 32153 why is the weight not 70?  visit 1=20 (PC) and max visit is UnRef=50

Comment: Doesn't matter as the visitRevenue will be calculated taking that into account.

Comment: For example like the one above but with two visits in a tie for WeightFirst PC gets a WeightFirst of 20 and DIR gets a 
WeightFirst of 40, then visitID 4479433 gets 0 for NatS, and visitID 4479435 gets 50 for UnRef. Total weight is 110. 
With saleID revenue in Sales being 516.00 I need to divide 516.00 by 110, then 
multiply the result by each weight and update visitRevenue in the Visits table with that result. 
So PC gets 93.81818181818182, DIR gets 187.6363636363636, NatS gets 0, and UnRef gets 234.5454545454545. Add those together and you get 516.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This, I think, does the trick.  I don't know your system so I did not know if you could alter the underlying tables so this does everything with table variables.

BTW, it **really** helps to have the tables set up first :)

```
DECLARE @weight TABLE (
        Channel varchar(max),
        WeightFirst int,
        WeightMiddle int,
        WeightLast int)

    INSERT INTO @weight VALUES  
    ('Dir', 40,45,50),
    ('NatS', 0, 0, 0),
    ('PC',  20,25,30),
    ('UnRef',40,45,50)

    DECLARE @sales TABLE (
        salesID int,
        revenue float)

    INSERT INTO @sales VALUES
     (32150,1600.00),
     (32153,516.00)

    DECLARE @visits TABLE (
        visitID int,
        salesID int,
        visitDate datetime,
        channel varchar(max),
        VisitRevenue float)

    INSERT INTO @visits VALUES 
    (4479433, 32153,   '2014-12-09 15:00:41.000','NatS', NULL),
    (4479434, 32153,   '2014-12-09 14:55:21.000','PC',   NULL),
    (4479435, 32153,   '2014-12-09 15:09:01.000','UnRef',NULL),
    (4755575, 32150,   '2014-12-07 16:41:24.000','NatS', NULL),
    (4756323, 32150,   '2014-12-07 16:52:56.000','PC',   NULL),
    (4756324, 32150,   '2014-12-06 20:49:41.000','Dir',  NULL)


    DECLARE @visitWeight TABLE (
        visitID int,
        salesID int,
        visitDate datetime,
        channel varchar(max),
        VisitRevenue float,
        visitNumber int,
        visitWeight int,
        totalWeight float,
        revenue float)

    INSERT INTO @visitWeight
    SELECT visitID, v.salesID, visitDate,channel,visitRevenue,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v.salesID ORDER BY visitDate ASC) AS visitNumber ,NULL,NULL, revenue
    FROM @visits v JOIN @sales s ON v.salesID=s.salesID

    UPDATE @visitWeight -- this sets the first weight, also sets everything else to middle
    SET visitWEIGHT =
        CASE WHEN visitNumber=1 THEN WeightFirst ELSE weightMiddle END  
    FROM @visitWeight vw JOIN @weight w on vw.channel=w.channel


    UPDATE @visitWeight -- this sets the last weight
    SET visitWEIGHT = WeightLast
    FROM
        (SELECT salesID, max(visitNumber) AS maxVisit FROM @visitWeight GROUP BY salesID) AS t
        JOIN @visitWeight vw ON t.maxVisit=vw.visitNumber JOIN
        @weight w on vw.channel=w.channel

    UPDATE @visitWeight
    SET totalWeight = s.sumWeight,
        VisitRevenue = revenue/s.sumWeight*visitWeight 
    FROM (SELECT salesID, SUM(visitWeight) AS sumWeight FROM @visitWeight GROUP BY salesID) AS s

    SELECT * FROM @visitWeight order by salesID, visitDate
```

Comment: If you are really clever you probably could tune this into one huge query.  I have a tendency to split it up into small chunks so I know that it is working.

Comment: Many thanks user918967 - that almost sorts the example. But the weight, sales, and visits tables I have are much larger so can't be inputting the values manually such as     INSERT INTO @sales VALUES
     (32150,1600.00),
     (32153,516.00)

Comment: And the figures need to go in the visitRevenue column of the visits table.

Comment: I had to do the INSERT because I needed to get your data into my database (I do not have a table called 'Sales' so my query will not work without something there).  What you would do is just remove the first 34 rows of my query and then change the '@sales' to 'Sales', the '@weight' to 'Weight' and the '@visits' to 'Visits'.

Comment: I updated the query to put the data into the column visitRevenue

Comment: I tweaked the query a bit to update the visitRevenue column in the visit table.  Remember to change all the table names!

Comment: Thanks the query runs on my tables but after 3hours it was still running! Trying to work out why it's taking so long!

Comment: Perhaps there is lots of data?  Also, you could try indexing the table variables.